# Can a pointer alternatively point to a const empty class or a non-const class?

Tags: c++, pointers

Presumably not. Here is my use case:

I have two classes A & B.

```
class A
{
    B *b_;
};        

class B
{
public:
    B(): b_string_("") {};

private:    
    std::string b_string_;
};
```

I want b_ to always point to a B object. I want b_ to point to an "empty" B object instead of nullptr so that I can always dereference *b_ in a defined manner to get an empty b_->b_string. So I thought I would create a global "null B object": `const B null_b`. But I can't (naturally) use this A ctor:

```
A(): b_(&null_b) {};
```

since b_ cannot point to a const variable. If not a "null B object", b_ needs to point to mutable B objects.

Making the global non-const solves the problem but I want the protection of const so I can guarantee the "null object" never changes.

FWIW, this involves a large project where b_ is pointing to an vector of B objects in another class. I could add an empty B object to that vector but that strikes me as kludgy.

Is there a method or pattern to solve my problem?

Comment: I probably shouldn't suggest this but... const_cast ?

Comment: Are you looking for Flyweight? But, bear in mind that all pointers would logically be const

Comment: @Borgleader how would that help here? You can't at runtime decide to const_cast the pointer to be const (if it points to your Nil Object)

Comment: Yes it can, *iff* it's a pointer to `const`.

Comment: You can't really get away from the fact that dereferncing a non-const pointer can modify the target. This can happen so what do you want to happen? Abort or something?

Comment: @NeilKirk I want to be able to dereference the non-const pointer when not pointing to a "null object" as I want to modify the dereferenced object. It is the "null object" that must never change.

Comment: But you have no way of preventing the pointer from being deferenced when pointing to the empty object. If you know when it points to the empty object so not to do it, then you would just use an empty string directly.

Comment: @Macbeth'sEnigma So basically, if you dereference the ptr and it's the null object, nothing should be called?

Comment: @Borgleader If a dereferenced ptr points to the null object, then I want access to the object's empty variables (directly or via accessors). This avoids having to check for the nullptr whenever I need to dereference which is frequent including operator overloads.

Comment: @Macbeth'sEnigma What I want to know, is you said that the null object should not change. What should happen if someone attempts to call a method on a null object that would modify it? Should it fail to compile?

Comment: @Borgleader Well, yes -- I'm looking for the protection of const (compile failure) if the program tries to modify the null object. It wouldn't be a null object if modified. Be vaguely akin to modifying nullptr. I am at least looking for some way to guarantee it can't be modified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of holding a pointer to a `B` object, create a base class with virtual methods and store pointers to that. Derive both your `B` class and a `Null_B` class from it, but don't let methods on `Null_B` do modifications. Now even though your `Null_B` object won't be `const`, it doesn't matter anymore.

As an extra layer of protection you could make any attempt to modify the `null_b` object throw an exception so that you can detect and find your logic error.

Comment: A working example (except that Null_B derrives directly from B) here: https://ideone.com/m5ezfh

Comment: @bill and markransom -- Thanks that is going to work. Thanks for the code Bill! It made it immediately obvious. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can't have a "non-const" pointer point at a `const` object. And unfortunately, using `const_cast` to remove the `const`-ness of the object will mean that some code later can try to modify the object. (Note that it's undefined behaviour to cast away `const` unless the original object is non-const, so technically, the compiler is allowed to generated code that crash if this happens. Unfortunately, many cases, it WON'T crash when the object is something more complex than `const char *` or `const int []` - allowing the code to happly continue after overwriting your object that you didn't want to be written).

However, since the `B` class has a `b_string_` member that is private, no outside object could touch it, so you could ensure that any usage of `b_string_`  is done through a virtual function (or multiple virtual functions), then derive another class from `B` where the, and the virtual function(s) says "Sorry, you can't do that" when the code tries to modify `b_string` in the derived object.

Comment: The const_cast is UB in the first place, unless you know the pointee is actually mutable

Comment: Yes, my point was that if you cast away the constness, it doesn't stop someone from modifying it - it being UB is kind of beside the point at that stage, since the reason for making it `const` is presumably that you don't want it modified - and given average in most systems, it probably won't crash, so it will just happily work along with the object being accessible and weird things happening.

Comment: Modifying it could very well crash the application. In fact this is precisely what happens when you **[write through a `const char*` in the average hello-world level app](http://ideone.com/30zoCA)**. I guess my point is "UB is never beside the point"

Comment: And you know of an OS/Compiler combination where it does? I'm not saying it can't happen, just that I'm not aware of such a combination.

Comment: That's not the same as a `const B` object, tho'. a `const char *` is definitely stored in read only memory, and will indeed crash. It's actually WORSE when it doesn't crash - because it happily trundles along after having modified the object you thought was `const` and couldn't be modified. But if it makes you happier, I'll edit in a "and this is undefined behaviour".

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You started me thinking on the right path. I did give the check mark to Mark and Bill because they made it a bit more concrete for me. I hope that is OK.

Answer (score 1):

Well, maybe it's totally off the point, but... Could you use instance of B instead of pointer to B inside A? This would solve potential nullptr dereferencing.

**EDIT** well, if B is too big, then you can create a lightweight wrapper around it, and store instance of that wrapper inside A. The wrapper would provide you something meaningful if B is nullptr.

Comment: No -- I have to point to this rather complex structure in the real project. Not only would I not want the overhead of copying I need to update it and not a copy.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I think in essence Mark and Bill's solution was a short and sweet wrapper around the null object that you were suggesting.